# Updating has many records via nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have two models, users and user locations. A user has many user locations.

I have an update action that receives the following params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"auth_token=", "user"=> "user_locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3", "address"=>"Charles Sturt University", "postal_code_id"=>"0872", "radius"=>"4", "latitude"=>"-32.2327054", "longitude"=>"148.6272543", "suburb_id"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"4", "address"=>"Charles Sturt University", "postal_code_id"=>"2003", "radius"=>"4", "latitude"=>"-35.2819998", "longitude"=>"149.1286843", "suburb_id"=>"1"}}}, "id"=>"2", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update"}
```

In the update action I have

```
if user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to users_url
else
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

The relevant view code

```
- @data[:user].user_locations.each_with_index do |location, n|
      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[id]]]" value="#{location.id}" type="hidden"

      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[address]]]" value="#{ location.address }"  type="text"

      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[postal_code_id]]" value="#{ if location.postal_code then location.postal_code.code end }" type="text"

      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[radius]]]" value="#{ location.radius }" type="text"

      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[latitude]]]" value="#{ location.latitude }" type="text"

      input name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[longitude]]]" value="#{ location.longitude }" type="text"

      select.form-control name="user[user_locations_attributes[#{n}[suburb_id]]" type="text"
        - @data[:suburbs].each do |suburb|
          - if suburb.id == location.suburb.id
            option value="#{suburb.id}" selected='' = suburb.name
          - else
            option value="#{suburb.id}" = suburb.name
```

Now the problem is that though the `update_attributes` return's true, Rails ends up replicating the records, so I then have two user location records for the user instead of just one updated record. If I update either one again, then it replicates the two records to four records and etc. I'm not sure what's wrong. How can I fix this to update the records and not create new ones.

Comment: Can you post your view code as well?

Comment: Posted it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: read the [docs for fields_for helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) and replace the ugly input declarations and the each_with_index loop with

```
= fields_for :locations do |location|
  = location.text_field :address
  = location.text_field :postal_code_id
  = and.so.on
```

Second thing: use `user.update` instead of `user.update_attributes`, cause that last one is deprecated.

Third don't forget to add `:location_attributes` to your user_params permit statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect scenario for using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) and [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) to let Rails handle all of the nested associations work.

Here's a good tutorial explaining it all: http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/